# apache eats up too much ram per child

Tags: apache-2.2, memory-usage

I've got fallowing problem: Apache eat to many ram per child.

The fallowing comments shows:

1. cat /etc/redhat-release -- Fedora release 8 (Werewolf)
2. free -m:

> ```
>              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
> Mem:          3566       3136        429          0        339       1907
> -/+ buffers/cache:        889       2676
> Swap:         4322          0       4322
> ```

I know that you will say that there is nothing to worry about because swap is not use, but i think it's not use for now.

3.httpd -v:

> Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix)

4.httpd -l:

> Compiled in modules:
>
> core.c
>
> mod_authn_file.c
>
> mod_authn_default.c
>
> mod_authz_host.c
>
> mod_authz_groupfile.c
>
> mod_authz_user.c
>
> mod_authz_default.c
>
> mod_auth_basic.c
>
> mod_include.c
>
> mod_filter.c
>
> mod_log_config.c
>
> mod_env.c
>
> mod_setenvif.c
>
> mod_version.c
>
> mod_ssl.c
>
> prefork.c
>
> http_core.c
>
> mod_mime.c
>
> mod_status.c
>
> mod_autoindex.c
>
> mod_asis.c
>
> mod_cgi.c
>
> mod_negotiation.c
>
> mod_dir.c
>
> mod_actions.c
>
> mod_userdir.c
>
> mod_alias.c
>
> mod_rewrite.c
>
> mod_so.c

5.List of loaded dynamic modules:

> LoadModule authz_host_module
>
> modules/mod_authz_host.so LoadModule
>
> include_module modules/mod_include.so
>
> LoadModule log_config_module
>
> modules/mod_log_config.so LoadModule
>
> setenvif_module
>
> modules/mod_setenvif.so LoadModule
>
> mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
>
> LoadModule autoindex_module
>
> modules/mod_autoindex.so LoadModule
>
> vhost_alias_module
>   modules/mod_vhost_alias.so LoadModule
>
> negotiation_module
>
> modules/mod_negotiation.so LoadModule
>
> dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
>
> LoadModule alias_module
>
> modules/mod_alias.so LoadModule
>
> rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
>
> LoadModule proxy_module
>
> modules/mod_proxy.so LoadModule
>
> cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

6.My prefrok directive

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   25
ServerLimit       80
MaxClients        80
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

KeepAliveTimeout 6
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAlive On
```

7.top -u apache: ctrl+ M

```
top - 09:19:42 up 2 days, 19 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.85, 0.87, 0.80
Tasks: 113 total,   1 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  7.3%us, 15.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 75.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.7%hi,  0.7%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3652120k total,  3149964k used,   502156k free,   348048k buffers
Swap:  4425896k total,        0k used,  4425896k free,  1944952k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
16956 apache    20   0  700m 135m 100m S  0.0  3.8   2:16.78 httpd
16953 apache    20   0  565m 130m  96m S  0.0  3.7   1:57.26 httpd
16957 apache    20   0  587m 129m 102m S  0.0  3.6   1:47.41 httpd
16955 apache    20   0  567m 126m  93m S  0.0  3.6   1:43.60 httpd
17494 apache    20   0  626m 125m  96m S  0.0  3.5   1:58.77 httpd
17515 apache    20   0  540m 120m  88m S  0.0  3.4   1:45.57 httpd
17516 apache    20   0  573m 120m  88m S  0.0  3.4   1:50.51 httpd
16954 apache    20   0  551m 120m  88m S  0.0  3.4   1:52.47 httpd
17493 apache    20   0  586m 120m  94m S  0.0  3.4   1:51.02 httpd
17279 apache    20   0  568m 117m  87m S 16.0  3.3   1:51.87 httpd
17302 apache    20   0  560m 116m  90m S  0.3  3.3   1:59.06 httpd
17495 apache    20   0  551m 116m  89m S  0.0  3.3   1:47.51 httpd
17277 apache    20   0  476m 114m  81m S  0.0  3.2   1:37.14 httpd
30097 apache    20   0  536m 113m  83m S  0.0  3.2   1:47.38 httpd
30112 apache    20   0  530m 112m  81m S  0.0  3.2   1:40.15 httpd
17513 apache    20   0  516m 112m  85m S  0.0  3.1   1:43.92 httpd
16958 apache    20   0  554m 111m  82m S  0.0  3.1   1:44.18 httpd
 1617 apache    20   0  487m 111m  85m S  0.0  3.1   1:31.67 httpd
16952 apache    20   0  461m 107m  75m S  0.0  3.0   1:13.71 httpd
16951 apache    20   0  462m 103m  76m S  0.0  2.9   1:28.05 httpd
17278 apache    20   0  497m 103m  76m S  0.0  2.9   1:31.25 httpd
17403 apache    20   0  537m 102m  79m S  0.0  2.9   1:52.24 httpd
25081 apache    20   0  412m 101m  70m S  0.0  2.8   1:01.74 httpd
```

I guess thats all information needed to help me solve this problem.
I think the virt memory is to big, the same res. The consumption of ram is increasing all the time. Maybe it's memory leak because i see there is so many static modules compiled.

Could someone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance.

8.ldd /usr/sbin/httpd

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x0012d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0012e000)
libpcre.so.0 => /lib/libpcre.so.0 (0x00157000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x0017f000)
libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x0019a000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x001b4000)
libldap-2.3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libldap-2.3.so.0 (0x001e6000)
liblber-2.3.so.0 => /usr/lib/liblber-2.3.so.0 (0x00220000)
libdb-4.6.so => /lib/libdb-4.6.so (0x0022e000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00370000)
libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00391000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x003b9000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x003d2000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x003d7000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00110000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/libuuid.so.1 (0x00530000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x00534000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00548000)
libssl.so.6 => /lib/libssl.so.6 (0x00561000)
libcrypto.so.6 => /lib/libcrypto.so.6 (0x005a6000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x006d9000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00707000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0079a000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0079d000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x007c3000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x007d6000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x007df000)
```

---

Currently i cant restart the apache. I work in a company and now there is rush hours. I will do that about 5 pm.

Current top -u apache: shift + M

```
top - 12:31:33 up 2 days,  3:30,  1 user,  load average: 0.73, 0.80, 0.79
Tasks: 114 total,   1 running, 113 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.3%us,  4.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 90.0%id,  1.3%wa,  0.3%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3652120k total,  3169720k used,   482400k free,   353372k buffers
Swap:  4425896k total,        0k used,  4425896k free,  1978688k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
16957 apache    20   0  708m 145m 117m S  0.0  4.1   2:11.32 httpd
16956 apache    20   0  754m 142m 107m S  0.0  4.0   2:33.94 httpd
16955 apache    20   0  641m 136m 103m S  5.3  3.8   1:58.37 httpd
17515 apache    20   0  624m 131m  99m S  0.0  3.7   2:03.90 httpd
16954 apache    20   0  627m 130m  98m S  0.0  3.6   2:13.87 httpd
17302 apache    20   0  625m 124m  97m S  0.0  3.5   2:10.80 httpd
17403 apache    20   0  624m 114m  91m S  0.0  3.2   2:08.85 httpd
16952 apache    20   0  502m 114m  81m S  0.0  3.2   1:23.78 httpd
16186 apache    20   0  138m  61m  35m S  0.0  1.7   0:15.54 httpd
16169 apache    20   0  111m  49m  17m S  0.0  1.4   0:06.00 httpd
16190 apache    20   0  126m  48m  24m S  0.0  1.4   0:11.44 httpd
16191 apache    20   0  109m  48m  19m S  0.0  1.4   0:04.62 httpd
16163 apache    20   0  114m  48m  21m S  0.0  1.4   0:09.60 httpd
16183 apache    20   0  127m  48m  23m S  0.0  1.3   0:11.23 httpd
16189 apache    20   0  109m  47m  17m S  0.0  1.3   0:04.55 httpd
16201 apache    20   0  106m  47m  17m S  0.0  1.3   0:03.90 httpd
16193 apache    20   0  103m  46m  20m S  0.0  1.3   0:10.76 httpd
16188 apache    20   0  107m  45m  18m S  0.0  1.3   0:04.85 httpd
16168 apache    20   0  103m  44m  17m S  0.0  1.2   0:05.61 httpd
16187 apache    20   0  118m  41m  21m S  0.0  1.2   0:08.50 httpd
16184 apache    20   0  111m  41m  19m S  0.0  1.2   0:09.28 httpd
16206 apache    20   0  110m  41m  20m S  0.0  1.2   0:11.69 httpd
16199 apache    20   0  108m  40m  17m S  0.0  1.1   0:07.76 httpd
16166 apache    20   0  104m  37m  18m S  0.0  1.0   0:04.31 httpd
16185 apache    20   0 99.3m  36m  16m S  0.0  1.0   0:04.16 httpd
```

as you can see the memory usage growing up from e.g. res( 135 to 145)m and it will be growing up till memory ends. Are you sure that this option i set up:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   25
ServerLimit       80
MaxClients        80
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

KeepAliveTimeout 6
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAlive On
```

are correct? Maybe i should decrease some of them?

Another questions that bother me: I got e.g. static module `mod_negotiation.c` compiled into apache and the same module loaded as dynamic. Is this normal that i've loaded duplicated module. But when i want to remove dynamic module(mod_negotiation.c) from httpd.conf and then restart apache error appears. Now I cant tell this error message because i cant restart apache :(

---

Hello again:)
This is memory usage just after restart apache:

```
top - 16:19:12 up 2 days,  7:18,  3 users,  load average: 1.08, 0.91, 0.91
Tasks: 109 total,   2 running, 107 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 17.0%us, 25.7%sy, 51.0%ni,  4.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.3%hi,  1.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3652120k total,  2762516k used,   889604k free,   361552k buffers
Swap:  4425896k total,        0k used,  4425896k free,  2020980k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13569 apache    20   0 93416  43m  15m S  0.0  1.2   0:02.55 httpd
13575 apache    20   0 98356  38m  16m S 32.3  1.1   0:02.55 httpd
13571 apache    20   0 86808  33m  12m S  0.0  0.9   0:02.60 httpd
13568 apache    20   0 86760  33m  12m S  0.0  0.9   0:00.81 httpd
13570 apache    20   0 83480  33m  12m S  0.0  0.9   0:00.51 httpd
13572 apache    20   0 63520 5916 1548 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.02 httpd
13573 apache    20   0 63520 5916 1548 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.02 httpd
13574 apache    20   0 63520 5916 1548 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.02 httpd
13761 apache    20   0 63388 5128  860 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 httpd
13762 apache    20   0 63388 5128  860 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 httpd
13763 apache    20   0 63388 5128  860 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 httpd
```

I will try to compile apache from source to newest version. Thx for help guys.

Answer (score 3):

From Apache [2.2.15 Changelog](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.2.15) there is memory leaks fix in 2.2.15 but if you top output is after apache start it's really huge from my point of view.
Did you try a worker config ? 
Could you add the output of ldd tool on you httpd binary ?

Comment: Hell radius, thanks for answer.
The top output is after working apache several hours i guess.
No i didn't try worker config. Should i install it from repository?

ldd /usr/sbin/httpd

Comment: Hello radius, Thanks for fast answer.
The output is after working apache several hours i guess.
No i didn't try worker module. Should i install it from repository?

ldd /usr/sbin/httpd
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x0012d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0012e000)
libpcre.so.0 => /lib/libpcre.so.0 (0x00157000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x0017f000)
libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x0019a000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x001b4000)
libldap-2.3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libldap-2.3.so.0 (0x001e6000)

Comment: liblber-2.3.so.0 => /usr/lib/liblber-2.3.so.0 (0x00220000)
        libdb-4.6.so => /lib/libdb-4.6.so (0x0022e000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00370000)
        libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00391000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x003b9000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x003d2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x003d7000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00110000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/libuuid.so.1 (0x00530000)

Comment: libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x00534000)
        libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00548000)
        libssl.so.6 => /lib/libssl.so.6 (0x00561000)
        libcrypto.so.6 => /lib/libcrypto.so.6 (0x005a6000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x006d9000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00707000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0079a000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0079d000)

Comment: libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x007c3000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x007d6000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x007df000)

Comment: sorry for this form of output ldd commend.

Comment: You could add the output to your original post using edit.
Try to restart apache and see memory usage just after a restart, I guess it will probably be OK. If it is you can hope that 2.2.15 will fix the leak.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry if I were you. free says that you uses 800MB and have about 2GB free.
Apache is not very lightweight server and you have a lot of modules on.